# Variables in Command Throw Error

Tags: powershell, office365

I have been fighting a silly problem where when I try to use variables in a particular command I get an error, however if I use the actual variable values instead it works. Why cannot I use variables here and what is the workaround? Help please. The variables all have the correct values in them. I verified everything works until the last line is executed...

(The last line in this code throws the error...)

```
#####################################################################
# Prompt for user input regarding deleted and destination mailboxes #
#####################################################################

# Ask for Deleted Mailbox SMTP Address 
$DeletedMailbox = Read-Host "Enter Primary Address of Deleted Mailbox: "

# Ask for Destination Mailbox SMTP Address
$DestinationMailbox = Read-Host "Enter Primary Address of Destination Recovery Mailbox: "

#############################################################
# Query for the Exchange GUID information of both Mailboxes #
#############################################################
$DeletedGUID = Get-Mailbox -SoftDeletedMailbox -Identity $DeletedMailbox |
               Select ExchangeGUID | FT -HideTableHeaders

$DestinationGUID = Get-Mailbox -Identity $DestinationMailbox |
                   Select ExchangeGUID | FT -HideTableHeaders

############################################################################
# Initiate the Restore Request from Deleted mailbox to destination mailbox #
############################################################################
New-MailboxRestoreRequest -SourceMailbox $DeletedGUID -TargetMailbox $DestinationGUID -AllowLegacyDNMismatch
```

**Error it Throws....**

```
Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'SourceMailbox'. Cannot convert
the "System.Collections.ArrayList" value of type "System.Collections.ArrayList"
to type "Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.MailboxIdParameter".
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [New-MailboxRestoreRequest], ParameterBindin...mationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,New- MailboxRestoreRequest
    + PSComputerName        : ps.outlook.com
```

Answer (score 2):

Apparently `$DeletedGUID` is a list, not a single element. Either pick an element from the list:

```
New-MailboxRestoreRequest -SourceMailbox $DeletedGUID[0] ...
```

or run `New-MailboxRestoreRequest` in a loop:

```
$DeletedGUID | ForEach-Object {
  New-MailboxRestoreRequest -SourceMailbox $_ ...
}
```

Also, replace

```
...| Select ExchangeGUID | FT -HideTableHeaders
```

with

```
Select -Expand ExchangeGUID
```

`Format-*` cmdlets are for output formatting, not for things you want to process further.

Comment: You'll need to apply @Ansgar's [0] suggestion to both of your GUID variable calls.

Comment: Assuming that both `Get-Mailbox` statements produce multiple results, yes. Another option would be to pick just one of the results (`select -First 1`), so the variable doesn't contain a collection in the first place.

Comment: Probably not in this scenario, but I've seen scenarios where Powershell will determine whether to create an array or populate a single value into a variable depending on the results. In these scenarios I usually force the return results into an array and then return the first value if I'm sure that is always what I'll want... `@(Get-Mailbox -SoftDeletedMailbox -Identity $DeletedMailbox | Select -Expand ExchangeGUID)[0]`

Comment: It looks like the `Get-Mailbox` function always returns an ArrayList object... https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb123685(v=exchg.160).aspx

Comment: That may be, but the pipeline should normally unroll the ArrayList, so that for an input ArrayList with only one item just that single item would remain.

Comment: I tried Ansgar's suggestions but now I have new error to deal with. Not much info out there about this error either....

Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'SourceMailbox'. Cannot convert the "b1aed248-7902-4455-8b2d-130546c24292" value of type "System.Guid" to type
"Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.MailboxIdParameter".
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [New-MailboxRestoreRequest], ParameterBindin...mationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,New-MailboxRestoreRequest
    + PSComputerName        : ps.outlook.com

Comment: @BrianF. I don't have an Exchange server at hand, but you should probably try the mailbox name instead of the GUID.

Comment: I wish it were that easy. We have to use GUIDs because of the way we transition accounts from one role to another. They get a new AD object with the same mailbox name as the original so there would be no way to tell them apart other than ExchangeGUIDs.

Comment: Try passing the mailbox object instead of one of its properties then. Not much else I could tell you. Like I said, I don't have access to an Exchange server here.